# Selecting the last entry of each day in a timestamp and corresponding values

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table called 'admin_tmp' with following structure

```
Field                 | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra
----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+---------------
id                    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment
time_stamp            | varchar(30)      | NO   |     | NULL    |
curr_property         | int(5) unsigned  | NO   |     | NULL    |
curr_property_cost    | int(5) unsigned  | NO   |     | NULL    |
day_property          | int(S) unsigned  | NO   |     | NULL    |
day_property_cost     | int(5) unsigned  | NO   |     | NULL    |
curr_solar_generating | int(5) unsigned  | NO   |     | NULL    |
curr_solar_export     | int(5) unsigned  | NO   |     | NULL    |
day_solar_generated   | int(5) unsigned  | NO   |     | NULL    |
day_solar_export      | int(5) unsigned  | NO   |     | NULL    |
curr_chanl            | int(5) unsigned  | NO   |     | NULL    |
curr_chan2            | int(5) unsigned  | NO   |     | NULL    |
curr_chan3            | int(5) unsigned  | NO   |     | NULL    |
day chan1             | int(5) unsigned  | NO   |     | NULL    |
day_chan2             | int(5) unsigned  | NO   |     | NULL    |
day_chan3             | int(5) unsigned  | NO   |     | NULL    |
```

Now I want to select last entry between two time values 7:0:0 and 7:59:59  (only date not the timestamp) for each day and its corresponding values

I am able to fetch only the follow using the below query,

**Query**

```
SELECT id, time_stamp , curr_property, day_property, mytime , mydate 
FROM (
SELECT 
*
,DATE(time_stamp) AS mydate
,TIME(time_stamp) AS mytime
FROM admin_tmp
) AS Result
WHERE mytime >= '07:00:00' AND mytime <= '07:59:59'
Order By mytime LIMIT 15;
```

**Result**

```
   id | time_stamp          | curr_property | day_property | mytime   | mydate    
------+---------------------+---------------+--------------+----------+-----------
 1225 | 2014-06-01 07:00:04 |          1641 |        11466 | 07:00:04 | 2014-06-01
13802 | 2014-06-03 07:00:05 |          1850 |        15452 | 07:00:05 | 2014-06-03
 7418 | 2014-06-02 07:00:05 |          1577 |        13053 | 07:00:05 | 2014-06-02
 1226 | 2014-06-01 07:00:16 |          1593 |        11471 | 07:00:16 | 2014-06-01
13803 | 2014-06-03 07:00:17 |          1577 |        15457 | 07:00:17 | 2014-06-03
 7419 | 2014-06-02 07:00:17 |          1528 |        13058 | 07:00:17 | 2014-06-02
 1227 | 2014-06-01 07:00:28 |          1577 |        11476 | 07:00:28 | 2014-06-01
 7420 | 2014-06-02 07:00:29 |          1545 |        13063 | 07:00:29 | 2014-06-02
13804 | 2014-06-03 07:00:29 |          1850 |        15464 | 07:00:29 | 2014-06-03
 1228 | 2014-06-01 07:00:40 |           981 |        11480 | 07:00:40 | 2014-06-01
13805 | 2014-06-03 07:00:41 |          1561 |        15469 | 07:00:41 | 2014-06-03
 7421 | 2014-06-02 07:00:41 |          1577 |        13069 | 07:00:41 | 2014-06-02
 1229 | 2014-06-01 07:00:52 |          1206 |        11484 | 07:00:52 | 2014-06-01
 7422 | 2014-06-02 07:00:53 |          1399 |        13073 | 07:00:53 | 2014-06-02
13806 | 2014-06-03 07:00:53 |          1545 |        15474 | 07:00:53 | 2014-06-02
```

I came to know that I have to use join to achieve this, but again I couldn't use join without any errors.

Comment: This might will help you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23707871/how-to-select-the-latest-record-of-each-hour-in-a-day/23730316#23730316.In that latest record from each hour is given.

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty i need to get max time for each date in the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would select the same data twice, one time to get the records, one time to get the max time per date. Then join both, so you filter such as to get the records for the max time per date only.

```
SELECT 
  rec.id, 
  rec.time_stamp, 
  rec.curr_property, 
  rec.day_property, 
  rec.mytime, 
  rec.mydate
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    admin_tmp.*,
    DATE(time_stamp) AS mydate,
    TIME(time_stamp) AS mytime
  FROM admin_tmp
  WHERE TIME(time_stamp) >= '07:00:00' AND TIME(time_stamp) <= '07:59:59'
) as rec
JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    DATE(time_stamp) as mydate,
    MAX(TIME(time_stamp)) as mytime
  FROM admin_tmp
  WHERE TIME(time_stamp) >= '07:00:00' AND TIME(time_stamp) <= '07:59:59'
  GROUP BY DATE(time_stamp)
) as max_times ON max_times.mydate = rec.mydate and max_times.mytime = rec.mytime
ORDER BY rec.mytime LIMIT 15;
```

Comment: yup this what i am struggling with and thank you @Thorsten Ketter

Answer (score 1):

Try this this will give you latest record for each day.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49aff3/3

```
select i1.* from InverterReadings i1
LEFT JOIN InverterReadings i2 
            on i2.myDate=i1.myDate and i1.myTime<i2.myTime
where i2.id IS NULL;
```